# Get values from JSON string - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

I have this JSON response string:

```
{"d":"{\"ID_usuario\":\"000130\",\"Nombre\":null,\"Vipxlo\":0,\"Provmun\":null,\"Descuentos\":null,\"Listaviplocal\":null}"}`
```

With this code:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
    //Check valid signal

    connection = nil;

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //data =nil;

    NSArray *jsonArray = [responseString JSONValue];
```

How can I do it?

Comment: It looks like you did it.  What else do you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This JSON should result in a Dictionary

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [responseString JSONValue];
```

then use:

```
[jsonDict objectForKey:@"d"];
```

Comment: Hi I've added  NSString *userName = [result objectForKey:@"Nombre"]; but I've got "variable is not a CFString at this time" value for userName. Do you why is it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm sorry but, ... I dont have any JSONValue class. Can someone suggest me how to get this class?

Comment: @SimoneDemoGentili See cortez' answer. OP uses a third party tool, that isnt needed for iOS 5+.

Comment: Where I can find this third party tool?

Answer (score 10):

When you can afford to require iOS 5 you should try [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Your code could look like this but I suggest reading the Docs first.

```
    NSArray* jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:someError]
```

Comment: NSJsonSerializattion  is the best and optimized solution compared to anyother framework.But [here](http://blog.skulptstudio.com/nsjsonserialization-vs-sbjson-performance) i found the pretty good solution for identifying the best among SBJson and NSJSONSerialization (Before the release of ios5.0 SBJSON is the good framework for handling Json objects).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [SBJasonParser](https://github.com/stig/json-framework) library for iOS.

You can then use this code (for all iOS versions):

```
SBJsonParser* parser = [[[SBJsonParser alloc] init] autorelease];
NSDictionary* myDict = [parser objectWithString: responseString];
```

**Note: Your code above has a JSON Dictionary but you were trying to access it as an Array.**