# No known instance method for selector 'JSONValue'

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, mkmapview

How to solve the above error?

I used the below code to get the latlong from address string using google maps api

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) geoCodeUsingAddress:(NSString *)address
{
  double latitude = 0.0;
  double longitude = 0.0;

  NSString *esc_addr =  [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=%@", esc_addr];

   NSDictionary *googleResponse = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: req] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: NULL] JSONValue];

  NSDictionary    *resultsDict = [googleResponse valueForKey:  @"results"];   // get the results dictionary
  NSDictionary   *geometryDict = [resultsDict valueForKey: @"geometry"];   // geometry dictionary within the  results dictionary
  NSDictionary   *locationDict = [geometryDict valueForKey: @"location"];   // location dictionary within the geometry dictionary

  NSArray *latArray = [locationDict valueForKey: @"lat"];
   NSString *latString = [latArray lastObject];     // (one element) array entries provided by the json parser

  NSArray *lngArray = [locationDict valueForKey: @"lng"];
  NSString *lngString = [lngArray lastObject];     // (one element) array entries provided by the json parser

 CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
 location.latitude = [latString doubleValue];// latitude;
 location.longitude = [lngString doubleValue]; //longitude;

  return location;
}
```

In the

```
NSDictionary *googleResponse = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: req] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: NULL] JSONValue];
```

line, I got the error **Automatic Reference Counting Issue: No known instance method for selector 'JSONValue'**

My project uses ARC.

How to solve that error?

Comment: Do you improt the "XXXJSON.h"?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762432/get-values-from-json-string-objective-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `JSONValue` comes from a category added on top of `NSString`. In order to use methods added through categories, you need to include the corresponding header. In this case, the missing header is probably

```
#import <SBJson/SBJson.h>
```

Comment: You also, of course, need to have the corresponding .m file in your build.

Answer (score 2):

`NSString` doesn't have a method named `JSONValue` (why did you assume it does?). Perhaps you should use the `NSJSONSerialization` class to parse the string into `NSDictionary` and/or `NSArray` data structures.

Comment: can't understand, pls mention what I have to do?

Comment: @NAZIK You have to read the documentation.

Comment: ***Do explain the downvote.*** (Which is **wrong**, since this answer is technically correct.)

Comment: Why would he not assume that there is a method on NSString called JSONValue, given that SBJson has been around several years longer than NSJSONSerialization, and the example he was cribbing from was using that method?

Comment: @HotLicks There was no mentioning of this framework.

Comment: No, but anyone with much experience with JSON on iOS would be familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through this problem ...

Do the following steps..

1)Go to Build phases->Compile Sources.

2)Set the flag -fno-objc-arc for all files which is related to JSON.

3)Clean the project and Build it again.

This error occurs due to ARC..as Our JSON kit have autorelease functionality while you are working with ARC..
Anyways,hope this helps you..
Good Luck !!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need the infamous SBJson Library.

```
[[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: req] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: NULL] JSONValue];
```

requires an NSString category which is found in SBJson Library.

Dont forget to disable arc for its classes.